# Excel Search for Text in Multiple Columns and

Tags: excel

How do you search multiple columns in one worksheet in a workbook to return a response in another worksheet in the workbook? I tried the following for each client name by day but keep getting a NO response when it should be yes (see Brenda Client Summary table below).

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*Bodar*", 'Brenda Client Schedule'!D$5:$D$32)),"YES","NO")
```

I currently have an Excel worksheet for each day in a given month with multiple client names in a cell by row by hour by day for a month called Brenda Client Schedule (below): Column "D" is the the column where the client names are stored by date.

```
##TIME                10/1/17 
8:30 AM           Bodar, Linney 
9:00 AM           Linny, Jones   
9:15 AM           Lawrence, Campana
```

In a separate worksheet I need to list each client by day for a month and indicate if they attended the session in Brenda Client Summary. Using the formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*Bodar*", 'Brenda Client Schedule'!D$5:$D$32)),"YES","NO")
```

it's returning a NO for each client each day when it should be YES.

```
Client Name   10/1/2017 
Bodar         NO          - Should be Yes
```

Comment: That is an array formula, are you using Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode?

Answer (score 0):

Use MATCH() instead:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*Bodar*", 'Brenda Client Schedule'!D$5:$D$32,0)),"YES","NO")
```